# Creating Java Web Service with Axis2 and classes

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am studying 'Web Service' this week and found good tutorial and example code.

[IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-devaxis2part1/index.html)

on the page of 3, you can see CheckCard.java file which provide Web Service on server side.

This file contains a few methods such as

```
public static boolean validCC(String number)
public static boolean validCCNumber(String n)
public static int getCardID(String number)
public static boolean isNumber(String n)
public static String getCardName(int id)
public String doCheck(String aCard)
```

and `'doCheck()'` method is the one I can invoke from client-side. What I want to ask you is why other methods are all static? Is this a rule or should it be static?

Web Service is very complicated for beginner and I just wonder every little things..
Could anybody give me a clue?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WebMethod ,in this case `doCheck(String Card)` is intended for remote method invocation and cannot be static. Doing so goes against the Web services model of relying on a proxy class, which, by its nature, needs to be instantiated as a genuine object to call the Web service.

That is why other methods are all static and cannot be exposed as a service.